# jQuery and input type=file

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

небольшой тестовый проект на rails+backbone. Суть: создание постов из картинки и подписи к ней. Модель такая:

post.js.coffee:

```
class TestBackbone.Models.Post extends Backbone.Model
    paramRoot: 'post'
    defaults:
        title: null
        path: null
class TestBackbone.Collections.PostsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: TestBackbone.Models.Post
    url: '/posts'
```

роутер posts_router.js.coffee:

```
class TestBackbone.Routers.PostsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @posts = new TestBackbone.Collections.PostsCollection()
    @posts.reset options.posts

  routes:
    "new"      : "newPost"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"        : "index"

  newPost: ->
    @view = new TestBackbone.Views.Posts.NewView(collection: @posts)
    $("#posts").html(@view.render().el)

  index: ->
    @view = new TestBackbone.Views.Posts.IndexView(collection: @posts)
    $("#posts").html(@view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    post = @posts.get(id)

    @view = new TestBackbone.Views.Posts.ShowView(model: post)
    $("#posts").html(@view.render().el)

  edit: (id) ->
    post = @posts.get(id)

    @view = new TestBackbone.Views.Posts.EditView(model: post)
    $("#posts").html(@view.render().el)
```

шаблон создания нового поста new.jst.ejs:

```
<h1>New post</h1>

<form id="new-post" name="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="title"> title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<%= title %>" >
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label> path:</label>
    <input type="file" name="path" id="path">
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Create Post" />
  </div>

</form>

<a href="#/index">Back</a>
```

представление new_view.js.coffee:

```
TestBackbone.Views.Posts ||= {}

class TestBackbone.Views.Posts.NewView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/posts/new"]

  events:
    "submit #new-post": "save"

  constructor: (options) ->
    super(options)
    @model = new @collection.model()

    @model.bind("change:errors", () =>
      this.render()
    )

  save: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    @model.unset("errors")
    @model.set("iframe", true)
    @model.set("path", this.$('form :file'))

    @collection.create(@model.toJSON(),
      success: (post) =>
        @model = post
        window.location.hash = "/#{@model.id}"

      error: (post, jqXHR) =>
        @model.set({errors: $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)})
    )

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))

    this.$("form").backboneLink(@model)

    return this
```

test_backbone.js.coffee:

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./templates
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./routers

window.TestBackbone =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Routers: {}
  Views: {}
```

пока поле path у меня было не файлом, а строкой - все было отлично. Но стоило мне заменить его на file - при выборе файла сразу получаю exception

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.

На файле jQuery на функции jQuery.fn.extend.
Как я понял, это в целях безопасности не дает изменять локальный файл пользователя. Но ведь я же не пытаюсь менять файл, а просто считываю его. Не пойму, в чем кроется причина такого поведения? Буду благодарен любому совету

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript из браузера не может получить доступ к произвольным файлам (даже считать). И это правильно. Если вы пытаетесь завязать логику вашего скрпта на подобный функционал - перерабатывайте логику. Например через загрузку файла на сервер, с последующей отдачей его содержимого на страницу.

Comment: понял. Тогда, наверное, не совсем по теме вопрос: в таком случае, правильно ли сделать так - страница создания нового поста не использует backbone, генерируется сервером, при добавлении поста просто отправляет запрос на сервер; а уже страницу просмотра постов реализовать на backbone? или вообще смысл использования backbone в этом проекте отпадает? Если вопрос не по теме - оформлю как новый